# How do I get a text "1+2" to display 3 which is achieved by inserting an = before it?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Some cells in my dataset read as say 1+1 or 5-1 (for some reason) instead of  2 and 4 respectively. How do i clean this up and make it display the appropriate figures

Comment: Its possible the content of this cell is actually \`1+1. The \` means, always treat as literal text rather than perform a calculation on it. You will have to manually go through each one of them, edit the cell, remove the \` if it exists and add the = if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you see `=1+1` instead of its result, that cell is probably formatted as 'Text'. Select it and see what Excel is saying about its format in the Cell Number Format menu. If the information is 'Text' you must change it to 'General' and then F2 and press 'Enter'.

Answer (score 0):

Before 1+2 you need to add =, excel will calculate, in addition, you need to check the format of the cell, in this case the cell is usually in text format.